# Wireless AP Placement and Digramming

Tags: wifi, access-point

I'm trying to research the best placement of wireless APs in a given space, and I'm running into problems in gathering information.

I found (what I thought was) a great source in this tech republic article: 
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5206-6230-0.html?forumID=82&threadID=163120

While this diagram seems detailed and overall very informative, there were a lot of comments talking about how it was lacking in things like "wire racks, microwaves, concrete walls, motors..." etc.

Maybe I'm rash, but I just sort of looked around my office (which is, albeit, somewhat smaller than the one diagrammed), and went "uhhh, there", and hooked up the AP. It seems to cover everywhere. I imagine if my office quadrupled in size, I'd logically divide it up and put four APs in, with a similar amount of thought devoted to each.

So, suppose I had a much more complex office. What tools (both diagramming and surveying) do you use to plan your AP placement?

Answer (score 1):

Matt, we use [this planning tool](http://www.airmagnet.com/products/planner/) from Air Magnet (which is owned by Fluke networks). Its amazing but [somewhat expensive](http://www.cdwg.com/shop/products/default.aspx?edc=1076838). But we found the tool indispensable.

For a poor-mans survey; you could use the [opensource tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) by polarcloud.com which has a good wireless survey tool built in the AP.

Rich